# Ethernet not working on Ubuntu 16.04 using Realtek RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 02)

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, ethernet, realtek

The ethernet is working when I am booting windows 10 but not in Ubuntu.
I have some problem in Ubuntu also. Its first kernel is not loading but second is working fine.

I am using mobile phone's internet which is not fast ,so I want this to be fixed. Please help :(
Below are some details

```
$ lspci -nn | grep Ethernet
13:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 02)
```

> $ uname -a
>   Linux prashant 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
$ ifconfig -a
enp0s29u1u2 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e2:00:3e:2f:dc:3e 
          inet addr:192.168.42.180  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4026:6d31:19e8:7109/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5677 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:1
          TX packets:6009 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2661044 (2.6 MB)  TX bytes:1040973 (1.0 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback 
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3564 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3564 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:287576 (287.5 KB)  TX bytes:287576 (287.5 KB)

wlp18s0b1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:f1:a1:bf:dc:77 
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)



$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I have added below lines to interfaces file:

> auto eth0
>   iface eth0 inet dhcp

```
enp0s29u1u2 : is the interface for my mobile phone.
```

And also I have installed `0009-r8168-8.044.02.tar.bz2` realtek driver, but now its not even trying to search ethernet .I followed [install realtek driver](https://unixblogger.com/2016/08/11/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/) to install driver.

```
$ sudo modprobe r8169 && dmesg | grep r8169
[sudo] password for prashant: 
modprobe: FATAL: Module r8169 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic
FAIL

$ sudo modprobe r8168 && dmesg | grep r8168
[sudo] password for prashant: 
[53224.788817] r8168: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

```
$ sudo lsmod | grep r8168  
[sudo] password for prashant:   
FAIL
```

Comment: What is the exact result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe r8169 && dmesg | grep r8169`

Comment: I have updated that in my question above. r8169 not found.

Comment: How about: `sudo modprobe r8168 && dmesg | grep r8168` ...since you say you installed the *r8168* package.

Comment: Ok, I am updating in question.

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules If you simply disable Secure Boot, I am confident that your ethernet will work.

Comment: :) I am going to try this.

Comment: There is no Secure Boot option in BIOS.How to disable it.

Comment: Did r8168 actually load? `lsmod | grep r816` Was an ethernet interface created? `ifconfig`

Comment: I think its not loaded

Comment: `$ sudo lsmod | grep r8168       
[sudo] password for prashant:   
FAIL`

Comment: How can I install and load r8168 so that it detects my ethernet .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while Installing Driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076932/error-while-installing-driver)